# When Granolah and Gas were granted the wish of being the strongest in the universe, did they become more powerful than Beerus?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Both Granola and Gas at some point of the manga asked to be the strongest warriors in the universe. Does this mean the dragon turned them stronger than Beerus, or is Beerus as a god of destruction out of the equation?